# Disjunction Commutavity in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ltac

I would like to have an Ltac tactic which does the work of Disjunction Commutavity. Mainly, if I have a subterm `P \/ Q` somewhere in a hypothesis `H`, `Ltac Com H` will add `Q \/ P`as another hypothesis to the context.

I have tried supplying the commutavity rule via an axiom and `apply`it; but it only works for the simple hypotheses, for example fails in `R -> (P \/ Q)`; where it should add to the context `R -> (Q \/ P)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the setoid rewrite library, which allows you to rewrite with relations other than equality.  The following snippet shows how to replace `A \/ B` with `B \/ A` in a hypothesis:

```
Require Import Setoid.

Variables A B C : Prop.

Goal ~ (A \/ B -> C).
intros H.
rewrite or_comm in H.
Abort.
```

To implement the tactic you want, we just have to duplicate the hypothesis and rewrite in it.  Note the use of the `fresh` tactic, which generates a new hypothesis name.

```
Ltac Comm H :=
  let H' := fresh "H" in
  pose proof H as H';
  rewrite or_comm in H'.
```

Here's a demo of `Comm` in action.

```
Goal ~ (A \/ B -> C).
intros H.
Comm H.
Abort.
```

**Edit** The [Coq manual](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/generalized-rewriting.html) has a section on setoid rewriting.  Roughly, you can rewrite with *any* relation `R` in a hypothesis, provided that you prove that the operations that appear in that hypothesis are compatible with the relation.  For instance, if we take `R` to be `<->`, the above rewriting works because there are lemmas in the standard library showing that logical equivalence is respected by implication.

---

**Note** I would generally advise against letting Coq name hypotheses by itself: these names tend to be quite unstable, which often causes proof scripts to break. As a rule of thumb, you should let Coq choose names by itself if you are writing fully automated proof scripts, which never refer to automatically chosen names.  Here's another version of `Comm` that avoids this issue.

```
Ltac Comm' H H' :=
  pose proof H as H';
  rewrite or_comm in H'.

Goal ~ (A \/ B -> C).
intros H.
Comm H H'.
Abort.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. However I can't seem to be able to find more information on this Setoid library. What other relations am I able to rewrite ? What other lemmas? are there besides or_comm ?